# Computing standard deviation with a known mean

Tags: awk

I have many, two column files. Column 1 contains variable numbers while column two contains the 'true' of those numbers. 
i.e.

```
file 1
41619.442 41586.441
41474.2539 41586.441
41587.539062 41586.441
41623.996094 41586.441
```

How can I compute the standard deviation of column 1 based on column 2?
I have tried to modify the common:

```
awk '{delta = $1 - avg; avg += delta / NR; mean2 += delta * ($1 - avg); } END { print sqrt(mean2 / NR); }'
```

to get

```
awk '{a=$2}{delta = $1 - a; a += delta / NR; a*2 += delta * ($1 - a); } END { print sqrt(a*2 / NR); }' 11978.08984 >> test1.txt
```

but with no good results.

Comment: There is no way to find the standard deviation of a list of numbers with only the mean and a single number.  If I didn't properly understand your question or data, please clarify it.

Comment: I want to compute the standard deviation of all of column 1 based on the known value in column two (for file 1 the known value is 2, for file 2 the known value is 5)

Comment: If you have all the data, then you can already calculate the mean and standard deviation, so why would you worry about an imprecise mean that is already present in the input?  (based on the fact that the mean of file 2 is 5.5 and not 5).

Comment: I have oversimplified- the value in column two is not a mean per se but an initial value and I want to know how different the new column 1 values are

Comment: @JuliePelletier Statisticians will make a distinction between a true mean and a sample mean.  Consider a distribution from flipping coins (heads=1, tails=0),   The true mean of the distribution is known to be 0.5.  For any given sample, though, the _sample_ mean will likely differ.  Standard deviation formulas differ depending on whether one is using true mean or sample mean.

Comment: @ixel: If you understand the math of what you are doing, you should explain it as part of your question, or at least link to a reference.  If you don't understand the math, you should be asking this question on [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com) or one of our other sister sites.

Answer (score 4):

First, note that column 2 in the examples is not the *sample* mean for the data in the files.  If it is the correct mean for the *true* distribution, then the standard deviation is:

```
$ awk '{ssq+=($1 - $2)**2} END { print sqrt(ssq / NR); }' file1a
61.4138
```

Here, the variable `ssq` is the sum of the squares of the deviations from the true mean.

The above program implements the formula for standard deviation:

[image]

where mu (*μ*) is the *true* mean.

#### Terminology

What I am referring to as the *true* mean is sometimes called the *population* mean, meaning the mean that one would compute if one theoretically had the entire population, not just some sample of that population.

Comment: John, cool! (+1); good idea to add the terminology.

Answer (score 1):

for this kind of problems, take a look at `datamash`:

```
datamash -W pstdev 1 < file1
```

Between many other functions, in datamash you have a

- `pstdev 1` = population standard deviation of column 1
- `sstdev 1` = sample standard deviation of column 1